# The $1997$ IIT JEE problem

Tags: geometry, inequality

> Let $S$  be a square of unit area. Consider any quadrilateral whose $4$ vertices lie on each side square $S$. Let the length of the sides of this quadrilateral be $a,b,c,d$. Then prove that $$2 \leq a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \leq 4$$

This problem appeared in IIT JEE $1997$ (re-exam).I really do not know know how to approach this problem properly.I have managed to prove $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2  \leq 4$
but not the initial inequality.

Comment: thanks for editing Mr Chinnapparaj R

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780018.

Comment: Thanks Martin R,I have figured it out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^2 = p^2 + s^2$

$ b^2 = (1 – p)^2 + q^2$

$c^2 = (1 – q)^2 + (1 – r)^2$

$ d^2 = r^2 + (1 – s)^2$

$$\implies a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = p^2 + (1 - p)^2 + q^2 + (1 – q)^2 + r^2 + (1 – r)^2 + s^2 + (1 – s)^2$$

Where $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ all vary in the interval $[0, 1]$.

Now consider the function
$y^2 = x^2 + (1 – x)^2, 0 ≤ x ≤ 1,$

$$2y \frac {dy} {dx} = 2x – 2(1 – x) = 0$$

$$\implies x = \frac 12$$

which$$\frac {d^2y} {dx^2} = 4$$ i.e. positive

Hence y is minimum at $x =\frac 1 2$ and its minimum
Value is $\frac 1 4 + \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 2$

Clearly value is maximum at the end points which is $1$.

Minimum value of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} = 2$

And maximum value is $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4$

QED.

Comment: You should cite the answer if you copied it from somewhere else. You just copied the exact answer from [here](https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Algebra/let-s-be-a-square-of-unit-area-consider-any-quadr_103212.htm) and posted it as your own.

Comment: @user982787, I seriously didn't know such similar answer exists, I myself was once a JEE aspirant and so I had solved this question at that time, like this, it was also taught to us like this in our institute. It's not copied or anything, but thank you for racing concern. Cheers! :)

Comment: @PradyumanDixit: Clearly, you've copied it almost word-for-word. It does not require one to be a genius to see that. No harm in citing the source rather than claiming it to be your answer.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit if you did not indeed copy then it would be wise to explain lines 6-8.

Comment: @hellHound there are not many words in the answer itself. I am seriously saying I have NOT copied the answer, in India we have an exam called JEE Advanced (previously called IIT JEE), from which this question has been taken. If I would have copied, I'd have tried to change the words. I didn't. I have done this problem same way, 10s of times, during my preparation. I almost remember the question word to word. This striking similar answer is because maybe the author at that place was student for JEE in same institute as mine, which wouldn't be a big surprise, as it's quite famous.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:
[image]

You want to find the minimum of:
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-a-b-c-d)+4$$

Or

$$-2.\sum(x(1-x)) +4 $$

Here x, represents a,b,c or d

Notice that it's a quadratic, so maximum of x(1-x) happens at x = 0.5 as it happens between x = 1 and x =0

So max of quadratic is 1/4

Hence,

$$-2.\sum(x(1-x)) +4  = -2.4.1/4 +4 = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

The smallest $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ is when the quadrilateral has its 4 vertices on the midpoint of each side of square S.  $a=b=c=d=0.5$, and the sum of the squares is $2$.  The largest is simply achieved when the vertices of the quadrilateral lies on the vertices of square S.  ie, both squares are the same.  The sum of the squares of sides is $4$ then.

Now why exactly is this so?  Let the sides of the square be $w, x, y, z$, and let the subscript 1 and 2 denote a section of the side (e.g. $w_1+w_2=w$).  Then $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=w_2^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2+z_2^2+w_1^2$. The restriction here lies in that $w+x+y+z$ is fixed, the perimeter of S.  We know that $2\times a^2<(a-1)^2+(a+1)^2$, for any $a>=1$.  Hence, since we are trying to achieve the smallest possible result, we would see each side of the square divided exactly in half, such that $w_1=w_2=...=0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Here’s my approach, I considered a limiting case for which values of a,b,c,d would be the least ,that’s when they are on the midpoints of side.So when the points are midpoint each side is $1/\sqrt2$.Thus the inequality will be $1/2+1/2+1/ 2 + 1 / 2 =2$.